# Rails 3 + rails_admin + MongoDB how represent an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rails-admin

Are there another ways of representing a array type field in rails_admin?

Now it looks: `- alsace - france - french - pinot blanc - dry`
where array items are separated by - symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I introduced transient fields for this:

```
class KnowHow
  include Mongoid::Document

  SPLITTER = ','

  field :category, type: String
  field :content_array, type: Array

  def content
    (content_array || []).join(SPLITTER)
  end

  def content=(items)
    if items.present?
      self.content_array = items.split(SPLITTER).map(&:strip).reject(&:blank?)
    else
      self.content_array = []
    end
  end

  rails_admin do
    field :category
    field :content
  end
end
```